# Can a separate .war bundle access the same hibernate/persistence of another .ear module (both run inside the same JBoss installation)

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, war, ear

I have an application deployed on JBoss 7 as an ear.

Can I add a separate module (.war), inside the same JBoss 7 installation, and use the same data-source
the original .ear uses ?

I am adding a new REST layer (.war) outside the existing project (.ear).
However, the existing project contains the database scheme, for which I want to add EntityBeans in the
newly created .war project, and deploy the new project too inside the same JBoss installation.

How can I achieve this ? Any pointers ?